# Can I pass the selected tab back from onTouchTap event of Material-UI Tabs component?

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I'm using the Material-UI [Tabs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs) component in my ReactJS app.

I'm handling the `onTouchTap` event of the Tabs component. I'd like to pass the *currently* selected tab back as a parameter to the event handler.

Is this possible?

So something like this

```
<Tabs onChange={props.onChangePosition}
      onTouchTap={e => {/* What */}>
```

I know that the `onChange` handler returns it, but I'd like to use `onTouchTap` in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. You need to capture a "ref" to your Tabs control, and then call getSelectedIndex() on it, inside your onTouchTap.  getSelectedIndex is somewhat internal, so it has an unexpected method signature in that you must also pass it in its own props.

```
<Tabs
  ref={ref => (this.tabs = ref)}
  onTouchTap={(e) => console.log(this.tabs.getSelectedIndex(this.tabs.props))}
>
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `ref`.